# How to run task defined in sbt plugin

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-plugin

In my project I use plugin which exposes task **genExport**. I can run **genExport** task from console with:

```
sbt genExport
```

My problem is I cannot configure my sbt project to run genExport after project compilation:

```
lazy val sample:Project = project
  .in(file("sample"))
  .settings(
     MyPluginKeys.someKey := "someKeyValue",
     compile in Compile <<= (compile in Compile) map { x =>
       println("----------")
       // ???
       x
     }
  )
  .enablePlugins(MyPlugin)
```

From sbt documentation I could not get how to invoke task from plugin by name. I've experimented with:

```
taskKey[Unit]("genExport").taskValue
```

without any success. What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val genexport = TaskKey[Unit]("genExport")
```

And

```
genExport <<= genExport triggeredBy (compile in Compile)
```